# What is the correct way of generating 'safe' JavaScript strings in Razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Razor automatically encodes strings.

But I'm confused how to work with JS strings generated in Razor:

```
var result = someFunction('@Model.SomeString');
```

As far as I understand here Razor will html encode `SomeString` but this doesn't mean it will be valid JS string.
I guess I can use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` method. But then should I let Razor futher enocde this string or use `Html.Raw()` ?

```
@{ var str = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.SomeString);}
var result = someFunction('@str');
```

or

```
var result = someFunction('@Html.Raw(str)');
```

What if this string is then used somewhere in JS code as inner text of generated html, when will it be properly encoded to avoid injections?

Comment: What do you mean "safe" JavaScript string? This depends entirely on the context and what you're tying to do. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @AntP I mean strings that can be later used as output text in HTML.

Comment: so, you need use `Raw` because otherwise razor encode html symbols and you will see it as text instead of rendered markup

Comment: @Grundy The opposite i guess if I want this text be text even if it looks like markup.

Comment: @voroninp so don't use `Raw` :-) and html will be encoded